# AngularJS accessing properties in returned JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following JSON object returned from my AngularJS app $http call and I am trying to access it from my AngularJS app html using the following code but for some reason nothing is rendered in HTML, so I am wondering if I am accessing the JSON object properties correctly? I will appreciate it so much if someone can please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correctly access the JSON object properties from the view.

Note: I made sure that the data is sent to the view through console.log which print customers list json obj to the console.

Thanks

```
{"Result":
   [{"customer":
        {"CustomerName":"Michael",
         "CustomerId":"212331",
         "Active":true
        },
        "salesid":19,
        "sales_name":"John West",
        "rank":["Sales Manager"]

...
...
```

In customers-list.html:

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="customer in myCustomersList">
            <div>
                <div>
                   <p>Customer Name: {{customer.CustomerName}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the response from your `$http` call as shown in your question is `data`. If you assigned `data` to `$scope.myCustomersList`, then your HTML should be:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="customer in myCustomersList.Result">
        <div>
            <div>
               <p>Customer Name: {{ customer.customer.CustomerName }}</p>
               <p>Sales Name: {{ customer.sales_name }}</p>
               Rank(s): 
               <ul>
                   <li ng-repeat="rank in customer.rank">{{ rank }}</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested your code and it worked but only after adding Result to myCustomersList in the ng-repeat so that it will be myCustomersList.Result, kindly update your answer with it

Comment: One last question though, assuming there is an array inside the JSON object, in other words assuming rank is an array, how I can loop inside all the fields inside the array of each object? Thanks

Comment: You can use nested `ng-repeat` for `ranks`. I updated answer to show that.